# Disable async Google Analytics loading

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have this code decorating urls with Analytics' cookie in my webpage.

```
var tracker = window[window.GoogleAnalyticsObject].getAll()[0];
new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker).decorate("http://www.toto.com");
```

This occurs an error :

> window[window.GoogleAnalyticsObject].getAll is not a function
>
> window.gaplugins is undefined

Like Google Analytics load its plugin asynchrously, i imagine `getAll()` and `gaplugins.linker` functions are not declared yet.
I can't wait the DOM ready, so i would like to force synchrously GA plugin loading.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#iframes) (cf Eduardo comments), we could Post a message to the child iframe :

```
 <iframe id="destination-frame" src="https://destination.com"></iframe>
 <script>
      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
      ga(function(tracker) {
           // Gets the client ID of the default tracker.
           var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');

           // Gets a reference to the window object of the destionation iframe.
           var frameWindow = document.getElementById('destination-frame').contentWindow;
           // Sends the client ID to the window inside the destination frame.
           frameWindow.postMessage(clientId, 'https://destination.com');
      });
 </script>
```

And in the iframe side :

```
 window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      // Ignores messages from untrusted domains.
      if (event.origin != 'https://destination.com') return;
      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {
           clientId: event.data
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of forcing it execute syncronously the best option is to use a callback function to execute your code.

Like this:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga(function(){
  // Code in here will only run after ga is loaded.
  window.tracker = window[window.GoogleAnalyticsObject].getAll()[0];
  new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker).decorate("http://www.toto.com");
})
```

Comment: Thanks but i can't do that.
My code is an iframe generator called in page loading like

    var iframeUrl = new window.gaplugins.Linker(window[window.GoogleAnalyticsObject].getAll()[0]).decorate("http://www.toto.com");
    document.write('<iframe src="' + iframeUrl + '"></iframe>");

And i can't change src attribute in a ga(function() {}) sin refresh the iframe content.

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation for loading iframes? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#iframes